# I am getting two results from this foreach statement.

Tags: php

I have an array of users. If the user_login matches the row in the table, it will select the id and name etc from that. With my below query it returns two links to 'Profile' one correct and one wrong. How do i get rid of the wrong one?

```
   function fetch_new_users()
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user_login']}'");
            $mysql = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            return $mysql;
        }

        $users = fetch_new_users();
        ?>
        <?
        if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {

        ?>
        <div class="fnav">


                 <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
                            <p>
                                <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" >Profile</a>
                            </p>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what you get in var_dump($users) ?

Comment: Try echoing `mysql_num_rows($result)` inside `fetch_new_users()` and see if it spits out 1 or 2

Comment: You should store ids of users in sessions instead of username(s).

Comment: Tangentially, you don't need to arbitrarily open and close php tags like that. If there is a `?>` right next to a `<?`, they are both unnecessary.

Comment: Why you want to loop actually when you'll be getting only a single result?

Comment: Your result should be 1, why are you getting 2 ??

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an array with the selected fields of the first returned row, i.e. `$users` will be an array with two keys "id" and "username". Therefore, there is no point in using a foreach loop here:

```
<div class="fnav">
    <p>
        <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $users['id']; ?>">Profile</a>
    </p>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning an array containing two variables, `id` and `username`.

By how you call it, you're expecting an *array of arrays*, so:

```
function fetch_new_users()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE username='{$_SESSION['user_login']}'");
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    return array ( $user );
}

<?php php foreach($users as $user): ?>
```

Note also that you're not checking that the data is actually there; `fetch_new_users` might return `False`.

Finally, there's not much use in a foreach loop here, because the function will likely return one single item. I expect you're reusing that code somewhere else, though.

So to wrap it up:

```
<?php

// If user_login is unset, fetch_new_users will fail, so it makes sense
// to check it *before* calling.

if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])
{
    $users = fetch_new_users();
    if (false === $users)
    {
         // The query failed. Output something to explain why we won't display profiles
    }
    else
    {    // This section will have to be closed later on

?>

    <div class="fnav">
    <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
        <p>
            <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" >Profile of <?php echo $user['username']; ?></a>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or you could check whether `count($users)` is 1 or not. The code above would then allow being used to display a single user's information, or the information from several users (which would have to be provided by a different function, or a different implementation of `fetch_new_users()` ).